# Invalid Password when logging into Jupyter in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm just starting to work with AWS and I'm working on getting Anaconda set up on my AWS EC2 Instance. The entire set up process worked well but i'm getting stuck with inputting my password in jupyter.

FYI, here is the tutorial I have been using: https://chrisalbon.com/jupyter/run_project_jupyter_on_amazon_ec2.html

I manually changed the password in the ipython config file:

[image]

Even when inputting `testing123` I get an invalid error message.

[image]

Have you guys dealt with this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have understood the whole process but got confused in password section so I am only gonna point out what you did wrong.

Assuming You followed below blog as you said:
https://chrisalbon.com/jupyter/run_project_jupyter_on_amazon_ec2.html

In the section 
**Create a password for jupyter notebook**

```
1 ipython
2 from IPython.lib import passwd
3 passwd()
4 'sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d'
5 exit
```

I have added the line numbers for the sake of better explanation:
when you write passwd() which is in 3rd line 
The AWS expects you to input a password and again ask you to verify the password you have given and then it gives you a SHA version of your password. like on 4th line: 
  `'sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d'`

Now you have to copy this and keep it with yourself to paste it later in ipython config file.

so you should use below lines in your config to make it work for you:

```
c = get_config()

# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always in your notebook

# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' #location of your certificate file
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  #so that the ipython notebook does not opens up a browser by default
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d'  #the encrypted password we generated above
# It is a good idea to put it on a known, fixed port
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you! On a side note, my port 8888 and 8889 are in use but i'm not sure how to vacate them, can you help me with this. I've asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406147/not-sure-how-to-vacate-jupyter-notebook-ports-that-are-in-use