# Not sure how to vacate Jupyter Notebook ports that are in use

Tags: amazon-web-services, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

The title explains it all. I'm currently working within AWS and am setting up anaconda for my projects. I'm trying to work on `https://XYZ.compute.amazonaws.com:8888` since that is the only port that will load in chrome.

Every time I exit my jupyter window and close my Notebook session, It shows that this port is still in use.

Any help on how to vacate these ports would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use 'Ctrl + c' on the terminal to stop the Jupyter server? If not, every time you try running Jupyter again it will automatically add 1 to the previously used port number.

Another way around is to [modify the AWS EC2 instance access rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) and allow other ports like 9999

Answer (score 0):

You have used screen. 
follow below steps to close the running sessions.

1. Reattach to the screen session (`screen -r`)
2. Hit Ctrl +c to terminate the Jupyter notebook session

If nothing works power off and on your server to free the ports

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with the question at hand?